# yii runcontroller in other controller actions with params

Tags: yii-events

// In my Controller A

```
class Controller A extends Controller
{

    public function action save()
    {
       $array1 = $_POST['array'];
           $A = $this->redirect(array('controller B/insert','data'=>$array1));
           echo $a;
    }
}
```

// controller B

```
class Controller B extends Controller
{
    public function action Insert($data)
    {
        echo $data;
        /*----code-----*/
        return value;
    }


}
```

I am newbie in `yii framework`. I have problem with, call controller b action Insert() from controller a with parameters but i have error:

> "400 Your request is invalid."

I don't know  how to fix it. please help me anyone..! Sorry for my English.. Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

You should call the controllerB like this

```
www.example.com/controller/action/data/somedata
```

You might have missed the data so its difficult  for the system to find the action